# Syntax error in awk if else

Tags: awk, syntax-error

I am using `if else` statements in `awk`.  Everytime when I use it I am getting a syntax error. Could anyone tell me how to use this? I am getting syntax error shown below.

Code:

```
awk '{ FS = "=" ;if($1 ~ /Hi/) {if (!($1=="Hi")) {print $1;}} else {if($1=="bye") {print $1;}}} else {if(if($1=="good") {print $1;}}} END {print $1}'
```

Output:

```
awk: { FS = "=" ;if($1 ~ /Hi/) {if (!($1=="Hi")) {print $1;}} else {if($1=="bye") {print $1;}}} else {if(if($1=="good") {print $1;}}} END {print $1}

awk:                                                                                            ^ syntax error

awk: { FS = "=" ;if($1 ~ /Hi/) {if (!($1=="Hi")) {print $1;}} else {if($1=="bye") {print $1;}}} else {if(if($1=="good") {print $1;}}} END {print $1}

awk:                                                                                                     ^ syntax error

awk: { FS = "=" ;if($1 ~ /Hi/) {if (!($1=="Hi")) {print $1;}} else {if($1=="bye") {print $1;}}} else {if(if($1=="good") {print $1;}}} END {print $1}

awk:                                                                                                                                ^ syntax error
```

Comment: Can you produce a short, reproducable example and post it here, an [SSCCE](http://www.SSCCE.org) , please?

Comment: Ya sure . I am editing the question

Comment: The `if` inside of the `if` condition is suspicious.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Please use proper code formatting. There's a button for it in the editor, click on the orange question mark if you don't find it.

Comment: No if I use this awk '{ FS = "=" ;if($1 ~ /hi/) {if ($1)) {print $1;}} else if($1=="bye") {if ($2)) {print $2;}} END {print $1}' ... then I am getting the output.. But if I add an another else if after the existing else if in a similar fashion, I am getting a syntax error

Comment: @JuhanaThank you.. I have formatted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problems

There are a *lot* of things wrong with your code. You have unbalanced braces, poor spacing, and other issues that make debugging hard. Ultimately, you have syntax and quoting problems.

#### Solutions

You can simplify your code by moving the assignment to FS outside your script. This is much more readable and less error-prone. For example:

```
$ echo "foo=bar" | awk -F= '{print $1}'
foo
```

You could also move your assignment to a BEGIN block for clarity, unless you are re-assigning it to something different at runtime.

```
BEGIN { FS = "=" }
```

No matter what else you do, if you refactor your code for readabilty, you will have a much easier time debugging your script.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is that when in your sequence of 3 right braces, you've finished off the whole script, so the rest of the line causes a syntax error.

You also have an `if` statement within an `if` condition.

I'm not sure what you *wanted* to write, but something like this might be what you were thinking:

```
{ 
    FS = "=";
    if ($1 ~ /Hi/) {
        if (!($1=="Hi")) {print $1;}
    } else if ($1=="bye") {
        print $1;
    } else if ($1=="good") {
        print $1;
    }
} 
END {
    print $1
}
```

At http://ideone.com/srNzp

Answer (score 0):

```
{if(if($1=="good") {print $1;}}}
```

is wrong. The first curly brace is closed at the second closing brace, where only one of the round brackets has been closed.

More: if(if seems pretty wrong. It might be healed when followed with other constructs, while in most cases you just use if (a && b)) to combine multiple conditions, or if (a) if (b) c else d.

```
 {if($1=="good") {print $1;}}
```

seems to be meant here. In a moment I will try to find more.

Yes - there are more unmatched braces. You could consider using Allman Style indentation, to get control over that: A newline in front of every {, and a new indentation level after that, until the brace is closed. Look:

```
awk '{ FS = "=" ;
if($1 ~ /Hi/) 
{
    if (!($1=="Hi")) 
    {
        print $1;
    }
} else 
{
    if($1=="bye") 
    {
        print $1;
    }
}
} // <- doesn't match any open brace
else 
{
    if ($1=="good") 
    {
        print $1;
    }
}
} // <- again
END {print $1}'
```

Many editors help in highlightening matching braces if you put the cursor next to one of them. You have at least 2 more unmatched closing braces.